# SharePoint - Rest - Fields Missing From Metada

Tags: 2013, project-server

I am trying to use SharePoint REST API to update a field's value on Project Task, but I don't see the field in the metadata, it lists out pretty much all the fields except for the field I am looking to update, does this mean the field cannot be updated using REST?

```
http://contoso/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects(guid'xxx')/Tasks('xxx')/
```

This returns all the fields except for the field I am looking to update.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, this means you have a field that is not standard with `?$select=fieldname,anotherfieldname` you can get all your fields. Drawback is that you get a Long URL and more typing, but filtering lists and lowering excessive data is **important**!

The exception to this rule as far as i know is datetime fields can't filter on them (Which is STUPID) and taxonomy crud is terrible so make a custom rest/webservice for it.

Do note that some fields such are **required** to fetch from a different list such as author id.

Example: `?&select=Author/id`